# Remove rows with missing data conditionally

Tags: r, dataframe, na, boolean-logic

I have a dataframe with some missing values, displayed as NA.

For example:

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1    4  3  6  7  2  1  2  3  4   1
2    5  5  4  3  2  1  3  7  6   7  
3    6  6  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4    5  2  2  1  7  NA NA NA NA NA
5    7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I would like to remove rows that have contain at least 80% of missing data. In this example it is clearly row 3 and 5. I know how to remove rows manually, but I would like some help with the code because my original dataframe contains 480 Variables and more than 1000 rows, so a code for automatically identifying and removing rows with >80% NA data would be extremely useful.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use `rowMeans`:

```
df = read.table(text='     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1    4  3  6  7  2  1  2  3  4   1
                2    5  5  4  3  2  1  3  7  6   7  
                3    6  6  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
                4    5  2  2  1  7  NA NA NA NA NA
                5    7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA')

df[rowMeans(is.na(df))<.8,]
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  4  3  6  7  2  1  2  3  4   1
2  5  5  4  3  2  1  3  7  6   7
4  5  2  2  1  7 NA NA NA NA  NA
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your prompt reply!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowSums` on the logical matrix

```
df1[rowSums(is.na(df1))/ncol(df1) < 0.8,]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1  4  3  6  7  2  1  2  3  4   1
#2  5  5  4  3  2  1  3  7  6   7
#4  5  2  2  1  7 NA NA NA NA  NA
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your prompt reply!